# Using lag function to find the last value for a specific individual

Tags: r, dplyr, lag

I'm trying to create a column in my spreadsheet that takes the last recorded value (IC) for a specific individual (by the Datetime column) and populates it into a column (LIC) for the current event.

A sub-sample of my data looks like this (actual dataset has 4949 rows and 37 individuals):

```
> head(ACdatas.scale)
    Date         Datetime     ID.2      IC       LIC

1 2019-05-25 2019-05-25 11:57  139     High      NA
2 2019-06-09 2019-06-09 19:42  139     Low       NA
3 2019-07-05 2019-07-05 20:12  139     Medium    NA
4 2019-07-27 2019-07-27 17:27  152     Low       NA
5 2019-08-04  2019-08-04 9:13  152     Medium    NA
6 2019-08-04 2019-08-04 16:18  139     Medium    NA
```

I would like to be able to populate the last value from the IC column into the current LIC column for the current event (see below)

```
    > head(ACdatas.scale)
   Date         Datetime     ID.2      IC       LIC

1 2019-05-25 2019-05-25 11:57  139     High      NA
2 2019-06-09 2019-06-09 19:42  139     Low       High
3 2019-07-05 2019-07-05 20:12  139     Medium    Low
4 2019-07-27 2019-07-27 17:27  152     Low       NA
5 2019-08-04  2019-08-04 9:13  152     Medium    Low
6 2019-08-04 2019-08-04 16:18  139     Medium    Medium
```

I've tried the following code:

```
ACdatas.scale <- ACdatas.scale %>%
  arrange(ID.2, Datetime) %>% 
  group_by(ID.2) %>%
  mutate(LIC= lag(IC))
```

This worked some of the time, but when I checked back through the data, it seemed to have a problem when the date switched, so it could accurately populate the field within the same day, but not when the previous event was on the previous day. Just to make it super confusing, it only had issues with some of the day switches, and not all! Help please!!

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you share your data via `dput()`, e.g. for the first ten rows of data type `dput(head(ACdatas.scale, 10))` into the console and copy the output starting with `structure(....` into your post.

Comment: Thanks Stefan! I have 189 columns in my dataset, so it's a bit unwieldy to copy the whole lot here - is there another way I can do this?

Comment: Hi Claire. Ok. I see. Just for the future: You could of course include only the columns needed to replicate your issue, e.g. `dput(head(ACdatas.scale[c("Date", "Datetime", "ID.2", "IC")], 10))`.

Comment: Oh thats so helpful! Thank you so much Stefan!

Answer (score 0):

Sample data,

```r
dat <- data.frame(id=c(rep("A",5),rep("B",5)), IC=c(1:5,11:15))
```

### dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(LIC = lag(IC)) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 10 x 3
#    id       IC   LIC
#    <chr> <int> <int>
#  1 A         1    NA
#  2 A         2     1
#  3 A         3     2
#  4 A         4     3
#  5 A         5     4
#  6 B        11    NA
#  7 B        12    11
#  8 B        13    12
#  9 B        14    13
# 10 B        15    14
```

### data.table

```r
library(data.table)
as.data.table(dat)[, LIC := shift(IC, type = "lag"), by = .(id)][]
#         id    IC   LIC
#     <char> <int> <int>
#  1:      A     1    NA
#  2:      A     2     1
#  3:      A     3     2
#  4:      A     4     3
#  5:      A     5     4
#  6:      B    11    NA
#  7:      B    12    11
#  8:      B    13    12
#  9:      B    14    13
# 10:      B    15    14
```

### base R

```r
dat$LIC <- ave(dat$IC, dat$id, FUN = function(z) c(NA, z[-length(z)]))
dat
#    id IC LIC
# 1   A  1  NA
# 2   A  2   1
# 3   A  3   2
# 4   A  4   3
# 5   A  5   4
# 6   B 11  NA
# 7   B 12  11
# 8   B 13  12
# 9   B 14  13
# 10  B 15  14
```

Comment: Add date to the grouping, such as `group_by(id, Date)`, `by=.(id,Date)`, and `ave(.., dat[c("id","Date")],FUN=..)`.

Comment: Thanks so much for this! I gave this a try and it returns the same output as the code in the question, with the same errors..... Do you have any idea why there are errors on some days and not others??

Comment: I see no errors in the question, and your data is not easily usable for me to test with. The format that Abdur Rohman provided (from `dput(.)`) is better, especially when your data has spaces or `POSIXt` or such.

Comment: The code works the same using Abdur's data (since their code is nearly identical to mine). The issue appears to be in your expectations and communication of the problem. If you use my code (and do _not_ include `Date` as a grouping variable), then your desired output is returned. Grouping by the date makes no sense given your sample data, since every date is different (therefore there is no lag to be had).

Answer (score 0):

By using your data:

```
mydat <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(18041, 18056, 18082,
                                           18104, 18112, 18112),
                                           class = "Date"), 
                        Datetime = structure(c(1558760220,1560084120,
                                   1562332320, 1564223220, 
                                   1564884780, 1564910280), 
                                   class = c("POSIXct","POSIXt"), 
                                   tzone = ""), 
                        ID.2 = c(139, 139, 139, 152, 152, 139),
                        IC = c("High", "Low", "Medium", "Low",  "Medium", "Medium"),
                        LIC = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), 
                               class = "data.frame")

mydat %>% arrange(Datetime) %>% group_by(ID.2) %>% mutate(LIC = lag(IC))
# A tibble: 6 x 5
# Groups:   ID.2 [2]
  Date       Datetime             ID.2 IC     LIC   
  <date>     <dttm>              <dbl> <chr>  <chr> 
1 2019-05-25 2019-05-25 11:57:00   139 High   NA    
2 2019-06-09 2019-06-09 19:42:00   139 Low    High  
3 2019-07-05 2019-07-05 20:12:00   139 Medium Low   
4 2019-07-27 2019-07-27 17:27:00   152 Low    NA    
5 2019-08-04 2019-08-04 09:13:00   152 Medium Low   
6 2019-08-04 2019-08-04 16:18:00   139 Medium Medium
```